# How to make a Java guessing game program

Tags: java, arrays, count, numbers

I am trying to make a guessing game program with Java and need help  Here is what I have so far.

```
public class CodeGuessingGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] guess = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] secretNumber = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    System.out.println("Let the game begin...");
    System.out.println("Guess my secret code, consisting of 1 and 2");
    System.out.println(" ");

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.print("Guess number " + (i+1) + " (1 or 2): ");
        guess[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Your guess: " + "[" + guess[0] + "]" + 
            "[" + guess[1] + "]" + "[" + guess[2] + "]" + 
            "[" + guess[3] + "]" + "[" + guess[4] + "]");

       for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
           secretNumber[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
       }
       System.out.print("Secret code: " + "[" + secretNumber[0] + "]" + 
            "[" + secretNumber[1] + "]" + "[" + secretNumber[2] + "]" + 
            "[" + secretNumber[3] + "]" + "[" + secretNumber[4] + "]");

}
```

The output of this code should be the following:

```
Let the game begin...
Guess my secret code, consisting of 1 and 2
Guess number 1 (1 or 2): 1
Guess number 2 (1 or 2): 2
Guess number 3 (1 or 2): 2
Guess number 4 (1 or 2): 1
Guess number 5 (1 or 2): 1
Your guess: [1][2][2][1][1]
Secret code: [2][1][2][1][2]
```

This code goes on forever.  You must be able to win or lose the game. If you get 3 or more numbers of the secret code right, you win. If you don't get 3 or more numbers right, you lose.  How should I do this?

Comment: So what is the output that is wrong?

Comment: The output isn't wrong. I just don't know how to count how many guessed numbers are the same as the numbers from the secret code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this at the end of the main.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   if (secretNumber[i] == guess[i])
       count++;
}

if (count >= 3)
    System.out.print("You guessed " + count + " numbers correct, therefore you win");
else
    System.out.print("You only guessed " + count + " number(s) correct, therefore you lose");
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can just define a variable a and increment it up one for each right answer. For example:

```
int a;

if (answer1 == true1){
  a = a + 1;
}

if (answer2 == true2){
  a = a + 1;
}

//check the rest
if (a > 2){
  System.out.println("You win");
} 
else{
  System.out.println("You lose");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split up the behavior of your code into different methods. For example,

```
public int void recieveGuess(int guessNum, Scanner scan){
   System.out.print("Guess number ") + guessNum + "(1 or 2): ");
   return scan.nextInt(); //Assuming the user entered an int. May want to check for that.
}

public int compareGuess(int[] secret, int[] guesses){
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < secret.length; i++){
      if(secret[i] == guess[i]){
          count++;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Then in your main you can just print the starting information, then loop through recieveGuess however many times you want, and then compare at the end.

```
if(compareGuess(secretNumber, guess) >= 3){
   //they won
} else {
   //they lost
}
```

Also you should just initialize secretNumber to new int[5]. This will create an array of length five with all zeros or whatever length you want. Then fill the secret number with random numbers. Like this:

```
int[] secretNumber = new int[5];
int[] guess = new int[5];
```